# Make a list of different types in Rust

Tags: list, inheritance, types, rust

In C# I can make a List and add items of different types to it. As long as they inherit the base class. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Parent
{
    public int p;

    public Parent(int p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class A : Parent
{
    public int a;

    public A(int p, int a) : base(p)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class B : Parent
{
    public int b;

    public B(int p, int b) : base(p)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Parent> list = new List<Parent>();

        A a = new A(10, 20);
        B b = new B(30, 40);
        list.Add(a);
        list.Add(b);

        A l_a = list[0] as A;
        B l_b = list[1] as B;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", l_a.p, l_a.a)); // 10, 20
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", l_b.p, l_b.b)); // 30, 40
    }
}
```

Rust is not an object oriented programming language, but I would like to know if something similar could be achieved. Is there a method?

Comment: `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>` is one solution.

Comment: Thank you! How do I convert a dyn trait back to a Type?

Comment: I cant use the "as" keyword

Comment: Should I add a function to the trait that returns the value/type?

Comment: The [Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait provides some downcasting (and more generally reflection) support. Though if your set of types is known and closed, an enum is what you'd generally use. Downcasting is not generally possible in Rust because structures don't keep their type information at runtime, trait objects only have the relevant vtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `Enum` and store it's different variants in a vector.

**Example:**

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

struct A {
    a: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn new(a: i32) -> Self {
        A { a }
    }
}

struct B {
    b: i32,
}

impl B {
    fn new(b: i32) -> Self {
        B { b }
    }
}

enum Parent {
    ChildA(i32, A),
    ChildB(i32, B),
}

impl Display for Parent {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Parent::ChildA(p, a) => write!(f, "{}, {}", p, a.a),
            Parent::ChildB(p, b) => write!(f, "{}, {}", p, b.b),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    let a = Parent::ChildA(10, A::new(20));
    let b = Parent::ChildB(30, B::new(40));

    vec.push(a);
    vec.push(b);

    let l_a = vec.get(0).unwrap();
    let l_b = vec.get(1).unwrap();

    println!("{}", l_a);
    println!("{}", l_b);
}
```